# Test whether a string matches a regex?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to check whether a string matches a regular expression.

```js
function isEqual(str)
{
  var re = /\/users\/(.+)/;
  
  // code
}

// Some examples of requests

console.log(isEqual('/users/1'));
console.log(isEqual('/users/1/Nikita'));
console.log(isEqual('/users'));
```

Comment: Hi, do rename your isEqual() method to isMatch() because you are testing does the string *match* the regex, noth whether it is equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the **test** method in order to get the result as a Boolean

```js
function isEqual(str)
{
  return /\/users\/(.+)/.test(str);
  
  // code
}

// Some examples of requests

console.log(isEqual('/users/1'));
console.log(isEqual('/users/1/Nikita'));
console.log(isEqual('/users'));
```

Comment: but in `console.log(isEqual('/users/1/Nikita'));` it's not eqeual.

Comment: Yes it is. I pressed the "Run code snippet" and it gave true, true, false for the three lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex work

```
function isEqual(str)
{
  return /\/users((\/\d+){1}(\/[A-Za-z0-9]+){0,1}){0,1}/.test(str);

  // code
}

// Some examples of requests

console.log(isEqual('/users/1'));
console.log(isEqual('/users/1/Nikita'));
console.log(isEqual('/users'));
```